# Average calculation

Tags: performance, r

I'm testing the influence of the time period on the end result of my calculations. To do this, I'm using a `for` loop, that is detailed below. In the current state of affairs, this code works well, but it takes more than 10 minutes to go through my complete data set. I believe the use of apply instead of a loop could speed up the process, but I can't work out how to do this. Some assistance would be more than welcome.

```
  ## result vector
  HLClist<-vector()
  Ts=3600

  for(i in 1:length(TimeSpan[,1])){

  StartTime=TimeSpan[i,]
  EndTime=TimeSpan[i,]+TimeInterval

  Xbis<-Choixintervalle(X,StartTime,EndTime)
  Xtierce <- resampleDF(Xbis, Ts)
  HLC<-CalcAverage(Xtierce$Ph,Xtierce$Ti,Xtierce$Te)
  HLC<-HLC[length(HLC)]
  HLClist<-append(HLClist,HLC)
}
```

Where

- TimeSpan is a list that contains all the startimes (format : double), defined as follows:

  ```
  InitTime <-as.POSIXct("16/02/2014 0:00", format="%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")
  FinalTime <-as.POSIXct("16/03/2014 0:00", format="%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")

  TimeInterval <-144*3600
  SEndTime <- FinalTime - TimeInterval

  TimeSpan<-data.frame(seq(InitTime, SEndTime, by=3600))
  ```
- TimeInterval is the number of seconds between Start and endtime (format : double)
- X is the dataframe containing all my data:

  ```
  X
                      t           Ph    Elec   Sol   Ti      Te        DHW
  1     16/02/2014 0:00     0.0000  612    0.0 22.70  4.600000     0.0000
  2     16/02/2014 0:05     0.0000  612    0.0 22.70  4.600000     0.0000
  3     16/02/2014 0:10     0.0000  516    0.0 22.79  4.600000     0.0000
  4     16/02/2014 0:15     0.0000  480    0.0 22.70  4.600000     0.0000
  5     16/02/2014 0:20     0.0000  540    0.0 22.70  4.600000     0.0000
  6     16/02/2014 0:25     0.0000  528    0.0 22.60  4.600000     0.0000
  7     16/02/2014 0:30     0.0000  492    0.0 22.60  4.600000     0.0000
  8     16/02/2014 0:35     0.0000  528    0.0 22.50  4.600000     0.0000
  9     16/02/2014 0:40     0.0000  492    0.0 22.49  4.600000     0.0000
  10    16/02/2014 0:45     0.0000  456    0.0 22.43  4.600000     0.0000
  11    16/02/2014 0:50     0.0000  480    0.0 22.50  4.600000     0.0000
  12    16/02/2014 0:55     0.0000  540    0.0 22.50  4.600000     0.0000
  13    16/02/2014 1:00     0.0000  528    0.0 22.46  5.270000     0.0000
  14    16/02/2014 1:05     0.0000  516    0.0 22.45  5.170000     0.0000
  15    16/02/2014 1:10     0.0000  552    0.0 22.45  5.070000     0.0000
  16    16/02/2014 1:15     0.0000  480    0.0 22.40  4.980000     0.0000
  17    16/02/2014 1:20     0.0000  420    0.0 22.40  4.900000     0.0000
  18    16/02/2014 1:25     0.0000  504    0.0 22.34  4.920000     0.0000
  19    16/02/2014 1:30     0.0000  408    0.0 22.30  5.000000     0.0000
  20    16/02/2014 1:35     0.0000  468    0.0 22.21  5.000000     0.0000
  21    16/02/2014 1:40     0.0000  540    0.0 22.20  5.000000     0.0000
  22    16/02/2014 1:45     0.0000  276    0.0 22.09  5.020000     0.0000
  23    16/02/2014 1:50     0.0000  252    0.0 21.99  5.080000     0.0000
  24    16/02/2014 1:55     0.0000  312    0.0 21.90  5.020000     0.0000
  25    16/02/2014 2:00     0.0000  336    0.0 21.89  5.070000     0.0000
  26    16/02/2014 2:05     0.0000  312    0.0 21.79  5.040000     0.0000
  27    16/02/2014 2:10     0.0000  264    0.0 21.70  5.150000     0.0000
  28    16/02/2014 2:15     0.0000  300    0.0 21.67  5.200000     0.0000
  29    16/02/2014 2:20     0.0000  264    0.0 21.57  5.200000     0.0000
  30    16/02/2014 2:25     0.0000  264    0.0 21.50  5.200000     0.0000
  31    16/02/2014 2:30     0.0000  360    0.0 21.46  5.200000     0.0000
  32    16/02/2014 2:35     0.0000  360    0.0 21.40  5.150000     0.0000
  33    16/02/2014 2:40     0.0000  264    0.0 21.35  5.100000     0.0000
  34    16/02/2014 2:45     0.0000  252    0.0 21.30  5.100000     0.0000
  35    16/02/2014 2:50     0.0000  444    0.0 21.24  5.100000     0.0000
  36    16/02/2014 2:55     0.0000  372    0.0 21.20  5.100000     0.0000
  37    16/02/2014 3:00     0.0000  372    0.0 21.11  5.100000     0.0000
  38    16/02/2014 3:05     0.0000  420    0.0 21.01  5.180000     0.0000
  39    16/02/2014 3:10     0.0000  324    0.0 21.00  5.120000     0.0000
  40    16/02/2014 3:15     0.0000  300    0.0 21.00  5.020000     0.0000
  41    16/02/2014 3:20     0.0000  420    0.0 20.91  5.000000     0.0000
  42    16/02/2014 3:25     0.0000  312    0.0 20.90  4.840000     0.0000
  43    16/02/2014 3:30     0.0000  300    0.0 20.80  4.880000     0.0000
  44    16/02/2014 3:35     0.0000  384    0.0 20.80  4.820000     0.0000
  45    16/02/2014 3:40     0.0000  324    0.0 20.79  4.800000     0.0000
  46    16/02/2014 3:45     0.0000  324    0.0 20.70  4.880000     0.0000
  47    16/02/2014 3:50     0.0000  432    0.0 20.70  4.980000     0.0000
  48    16/02/2014 3:55     0.0000  420    0.0 20.66  5.000000     0.0000
  49    16/02/2014 4:00     0.0000  336    0.0 20.60  4.920000     0.0000
  50    16/02/2014 4:05     0.0000  372    0.0 20.60  4.900000     0.0000
  51    16/02/2014 4:10     0.0000  384    0.0 20.56  4.980000     0.0000
  52    16/02/2014 4:15     0.0000  276    0.0 20.50  4.920000     0.0000
  53    16/02/2014 4:20     0.0000  276    0.0 20.45  4.900000     0.0000
  54    16/02/2014 4:25     0.0000  396    0.0 20.40  4.900000     0.0000
  55    16/02/2014 4:30     0.0000  288    0.0 20.40  4.900000     0.0000
  56    16/02/2014 4:35     0.0000  276    0.0 20.33  4.900000     0.0000
  57    16/02/2014 4:40     0.0000  444    0.0 20.30  4.800000     0.0000
  58    16/02/2014 4:45     0.0000  348    0.0 20.30  4.800000     0.0000
  59    16/02/2014 4:50     0.0000  372    0.0 20.30  4.700000     0.0000
  60    16/02/2014 4:55     0.0000  456    0.0 20.21  4.500000     0.0000
  61    16/02/2014 5:00     0.0000  384    0.0 20.20  4.480000     0.0000
  62    16/02/2014 5:05     0.0000  324    0.0 20.20  4.370000     0.0000
  63    16/02/2014 5:10     0.0000  360    0.0 20.10  4.300000     0.0000
  64    16/02/2014 5:15     0.0000  348    0.0 20.10  4.300000     0.0000
  65    16/02/2014 5:20     0.0000  324    0.0 20.10  4.330000     0.0000
  66    16/02/2014 5:25     0.0000  336    0.0 20.08  4.400000     0.0000
  67    16/02/2014 5:30     0.0000  360    0.0 20.00  4.400000     0.0000
  68    16/02/2014 5:35     0.0000  312    0.0 20.00  4.400000     0.0000
  69    16/02/2014 5:40     0.0000  384    0.0 20.00  4.400000     0.0000
  70    16/02/2014 5:45     0.0000  372    0.0 20.00  4.440000     0.0000
  71    16/02/2014 5:50     0.0000  360    0.0 19.96  4.500000     0.0000
  72    16/02/2014 5:55     0.0000  480    0.0 19.90  4.500000     0.0000
  73    16/02/2014 6:00     0.0000  384    0.0 19.90  4.540000     0.0000
  74    16/02/2014 6:05     0.0000  312    0.0 19.90  4.520000     0.0000
  75    16/02/2014 6:10     0.0000  396    0.0 19.84  4.400000     0.0000
  76    16/02/2014 6:15     0.0000  324    0.0 19.80  4.360000     0.0000
  77    16/02/2014 6:20     0.0000  312    0.0 19.80  4.260000     0.0000
  78    16/02/2014 6:25     0.0000  360    0.0 19.80  4.200000     0.0000
  79    16/02/2014 6:30     0.0000  372    0.0 19.80  4.200000     0.0000
  80    16/02/2014 6:35     0.0000  312    0.0 19.71  4.200000     0.0000
  81    16/02/2014 6:40     0.0000  324    0.0 19.70  4.150000     0.0000
  82    16/02/2014 6:45     0.0000  444    0.0 19.70  4.150000     0.0000
  83    16/02/2014 6:50     0.0000  408    0.0 19.69  4.150000     0.0000
  84    16/02/2014 6:55     0.0000  420    0.0 19.60  4.050000     0.0000
  85    16/02/2014 7:00     0.0000  408    0.0 19.60  4.000000     0.0000
  86    16/02/2014 7:05     0.0000  312    0.0 19.60  4.060000     0.0000
  87    16/02/2014 7:10     0.0000  384    0.0 19.60  4.040000     0.0000
  88    16/02/2014 7:15     0.0000  360    0.0 19.57  3.940000     0.0000
  89    16/02/2014 7:20     0.0000  288    0.0 19.50  3.840000     0.0000
  90    16/02/2014 7:25     0.0000  408    0.0 19.50  3.800000     0.0000
  91    16/02/2014 7:30     0.0000  336   11.5 19.50  3.800000     0.0000
  92    16/02/2014 7:35     0.0000  300   32.6 19.50  3.800000     0.0000
  93    16/02/2014 7:40     0.0000  360   67.6 19.45  3.730000     0.0000
  94    16/02/2014 7:45     0.0000  360  100.7 19.40  3.630000     0.0000
  95    16/02/2014 7:50     0.0000  408  125.9 19.40  3.750000     0.0000
  96    16/02/2014 7:55     0.0000  516  142.2 19.40  3.800000     0.0000
  97    16/02/2014 8:00     0.0000  552  162.6 19.47  3.950000     0.0000
  98    16/02/2014 8:05     0.0000  576 1386.7 19.50  4.000000     0.0000
  99    16/02/2014 8:10     0.0000 1032 1550.6 19.57  4.090000     0.0000
  100   16/02/2014 8:15     0.0000 1620 1705.0 19.64  4.100000     0.0000
  101   16/02/2014 8:20     0.0000 1236 1846.5 19.70  4.100000     0.0000
  102   16/02/2014 8:25     0.0000  876 1976.9 19.70  4.300000     0.0000
  103   16/02/2014 8:30     0.0000  912 2097.2 19.70  4.300000     0.0000
  104   16/02/2014 8:35     0.0000  756 2206.5 19.80  4.390000     0.0000
  105   16/02/2014 8:40     0.0000  780 2307.5 19.81  4.490000     0.0000
  106   16/02/2014 8:45     0.0000  912 2398.9 19.90  4.500000     0.0000
  107   16/02/2014 8:50     0.0000  816 2483.3 19.90  4.600000  2357.5261
  108   16/02/2014 8:55     0.0000  732 2559.9 19.93  4.600000  5087.2931
  109   16/02/2014 9:00     0.0000  744 2628.5 20.00  4.700000     0.0000
  110   16/02/2014 9:05     0.0000  684 2689.3 20.00  4.890000     0.0000
  111   16/02/2014 9:10     0.0000  636 2741.2 20.05  4.900000     0.0000
  112   16/02/2014 9:15     0.0000  372 2798.5 20.10  4.910000     0.0000
  113   16/02/2014 9:20     0.0000  240 2872.2 20.10  5.010000     0.0000
  114   16/02/2014 9:25     0.0000  240 2947.3 20.10  5.110000     0.0000
  115   16/02/2014 9:30     0.0000  204 3017.2 20.17  5.200000     0.0000
  116   16/02/2014 9:35     0.0000  216 3077.6 20.20  5.220000     0.0000
  117   16/02/2014 9:40     0.0000  228 3135.5 20.20  5.400000     0.0000
  118   16/02/2014 9:45     0.0000  192 3192.8 20.20  5.430000     0.0000
  119   16/02/2014 9:50     0.0000  132 3241.5 20.20  5.530000     0.0000
  120   16/02/2014 9:55     0.0000  108 3287.1 20.20  5.630000 12904.3533
  121  16/02/2014 10:00     0.0000   60 3330.0 20.20  5.700000  9554.1846
  122  16/02/2014 10:05     0.0000   72 3369.2 20.20  5.730000  1116.7229
  123  16/02/2014 10:10     0.0000   36 3405.4 20.18  5.840000  2233.4458
  124  16/02/2014 10:15     0.0000   36 2983.5 20.10  5.940000  5831.7750
  125  16/02/2014 10:20     0.0000    0 2428.1 20.10  6.000000  5583.6144
  126  16/02/2014 10:25     0.0000    0 2237.7 20.10  6.000000     0.0000
  127  16/02/2014 10:30     0.0000   12 2269.7 20.10  6.050000     0.0000
  128  16/02/2014 10:35     0.0000    0 2738.2 20.10  6.100000     0.0000
  129  16/02/2014 10:40     0.0000    0 3422.9 20.10  6.100000     0.0000
  130  16/02/2014 10:45     0.0000    0 3565.9 20.10  6.160000     0.0000
  131  16/02/2014 10:50     0.0000    0 3576.7 20.10  6.260000     0.0000
  132  16/02/2014 10:55     0.0000    0 3584.8 20.10  6.360000     0.0000
  133  16/02/2014 11:00     0.0000    0 3318.6 20.10  6.340000     0.0000
  134  16/02/2014 11:05     0.0000    0 2930.1 20.10  6.360000     0.0000
  135  16/02/2014 11:10     0.0000   24 2718.4 20.10  6.530000     0.0000
  136  16/02/2014 11:15     0.0000  144 2708.2 20.10  6.670000     0.0000
  137  16/02/2014 11:20     0.0000  360 2713.0 20.10  6.560000     0.0000
  138  16/02/2014 11:25     0.0000  312 2711.7 20.10  6.500000     0.0000
  139  16/02/2014 11:30     0.0000  252 2707.5 20.10  6.580000     0.0000
  140  16/02/2014 11:35     0.0000  492 2702.2 20.10  6.510000     0.0000
  141  16/02/2014 11:40     0.0000  144 2698.8 20.00  6.940000     0.0000
  142  16/02/2014 11:45     0.0000  564 2688.3 20.00  7.260000     0.0000
  ```
- `Choixintervalle` is the following function:

  ```
  Choixintervalle <-function(X,startTime=NA,endTime=NA)   {   

  ## set the start time if not specified   
  if(is.na(startTime)){startTime <- as.POSIXct(X[1,1], format="%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")}   
  else{startTime<-as.POSIXct(startTime, format="%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")}

  ## set the end time if not specified   
  if(is.na(endTime)){ endTime <- as.POSIXct(X[nrow(X),1], format="%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")}   
  else{endTime<-as.POSIXct(endTime, format="%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")}

  X<-X[(as.POSIXct(X$t,format="%d/%m/%Y %H:%M"))>startTime,]   
  X<-X[(as.POSIXct(X$t,format="%d/%m/%Y %H:%M"))<endTime,]   
  return(X)   
  }
  ```
- ResempleEDF is the following function:

  ```
  resampleDF <- function(X,Ts,startTime = NA, endTime =NA,timeName="t",includeNA=TRUE,quantizeTime=TRUE,meanNaRm=FALSE)
  {
  ## Split into periods of length Ts, and take the mean of each period
  X[,timeName] <-as.POSIXct(X[,timeName], format="%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")-startTime
  iSplit <- as.integer(X[,timeName]) %/% Ts

  ## Do the resampling
  Xres <- aggregate(X, list(iSplit), mean, na.rm=meanNaRm)

  ## Remove the "Group" column
  Xres <- Xres[,-1]

  ## Convert time to POSIXct
  Corr<- as.integer(Xres[1,timeName])
  Xres[,timeName] <- startTime + as.integer(Xres[,timeName])-Corr

  return(Xres)
  }
  ```
- `CalcAverage` is the following function:

  ```
  CalcAverage <- function(Q, Ti,Te) { 

  Solution = vector(length(Q), mode="double" )

  for (i in 1:length(Q)){
   Temp<-sum(Ti[1:i]-Te[1:i])
   Heat<-sum(Q[1:i])  

  #création du vecteur R
  Solution[i]<-Heat/Temp

  }
  return(Solution) 
  }
  ```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Your current question title describes how the code is structured, but what we really want in a good title is **the purpose of the code**. You can improve it with a small [edit] to summarise *the task accomplished*. Please also see [How to get the best value out of Code Review: Asking Questions](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2436) for guidance on writing good question titles.

Comment: Can you provide example `X` data using `dput` or simulating large enough data that we can run the code by simply copying and pasting the code, so wee can see the speed problem?

Comment: What is `Ts` object?

Comment: @minem, The X data frame is too big to be posted on line, the best I could do was to include the example code I did.  As for Ts, it's the number of hours for which I take the average, format = double, value = 6*3600

Comment: @K.DeSloover please check your code if it can be run, because, I currently cant run it, it yields an error in `resampleDF `

Comment: I changed the value of Ts and included the biggest sample of X I could manage, normally this should be enough for the resampleEDF function to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# GENERATE data
nmax <- TimeSpan[nrow(TimeSpan), ]
tSEQ <- seq(as.POSIXct("16/02/2014 0:00", format = "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M"),
            to = nmax, by = '5 s')
n <- length(tSEQ)
X <- data.frame(tSEQ)
set.seed(42)
X <- cbind(X, replicate(6, rnorm(n)))
colnames(X) <- c("t", "Ph", "Elec", "Sol", "Ti", "Te", "DHW")
head(X)
```

My approach using data.table:

```
require(data.table)
setDT(X)
# convert to POSIXct outside of the loop:
X[, t := as.POSIXct(t, format = "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")]
setkey(X, t) # adds key for possibly faster subsetting

Choixintervalle2 <- function(X, startTime = NA, endTime = NA)   {
  if (is.na(startTime)) {
    startTime <- X[1, 1]
  } else {
    startTime <- as.POSIXct(startTime, format = "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")
  }
  if (is.na(endTime)) {
    endTime <- X[nrow(X), 1]
  } else {
    endTime <- as.POSIXct(endTime, format = "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")
  }
  X <- X[t > startTime & t < endTime]
  return(X)
}

resampleDF2 <- function(X, Ts, startTime = NA, endTime = NA, timeName = "t",
                       includeNA = TRUE, quantizeTime = TRUE,
                       meanNaRm = FALSE) {
  X[[timeName]] <- X[[timeName]] - startTime
  # column names to be agreagated:
  j <- c("t", "Ph", "Elec", "Sol", "Ti", "Te", "DHW")
  # aggregate using data.table:
  Xres <- X[, lapply(.SD, mean, na.rm = meanNaRm), 
            by = as.integer(X[[timeName]]) %/% Ts,
            .SDcols = j]
  ## Remove the "Group" column:
  set(Xres, j = 1L, value = NULL)
  Corr <- as.integer(Xres[[timeName]][1])
  Xres[[timeName]] <- startTime + as.integer(Xres[[timeName]]) - Corr
  return(Xres)
}

CalcAverage2 <- function(Q, Ti, Te) {
  Solution <- cumsum(Q)/cumsum(Ti - Te)
  return(Solution)
}

HLClist2 <- vector()
ii <- length(TimeSpan[, 1])
for (i in 1:ii) {
  StartTime = TimeSpan[i,]
  EndTime = TimeSpan[i,] + TimeInterval
  Xbis <- Choixintervalle2(X, StartTime, EndTime)
  Xtierce <- resampleDF2(Xbis, Ts, StartTime, EndTime)
  HLC <- CalcAverage2(Xtierce$Ph, Xtierce$Ti, Xtierce$Te)
  HLC <- HLC[length(HLC)]
  HLClist2 <- append(HLClist2, HLC)
}
```

Should be much faster, because, the slowest part of your code was `aggregate` function. It is possible that the code could be speed up even more..., but I think that it should suffice now.

@t3chb0t Mainly I used data.table instead of data.frame for faster aggregation. Also, I converted the dates to PosixCt outside of the loop + some other minor things was changed, but they did not impact the speed a lot.

Comment: Could you explain your solution in more details? What did you do differently besides getting rid of the `aggregate`?

Comment: @t3chb0t Mainly I used `data.table` instead of `data.frame` for faster aggregation. Also, I converted the dates to PosixCt outside of the loop + some other minor things was changed, but they did not impact the speed.

Comment: I'd be great if you could edit your answer and add this information to it ;-)